# OpenXML SDK How to position an image in MS Word?

Tags: .net, ms-word, openxml

I did insert an image using the OpenXML SDK API .. however i can not figure out how to position the image to appear on any part of the page (probably using anything similar to (x,y) co-ordinates)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different kinds of images, inline images and positioned images. My guess is you're creating an inline image and need a positioned image.